# Alternative for an expensive for and if else loop

Tags: r, optimization, if-statement, for-loop

I am currently with a 500,000 observations of data and I have a step in my R code that does the following -

```
attach(ds) 
weight <- rep(NA,length(date))
sales_base <- rep(NA,length(date))
cumsales <- rep(NA,length(date))    

weight[dup_no!=0 & month(date)==7] = lag_sales[dup_no!=0 & month(date)==7]
sales_base[dup_no!=0 & month(date)==7] = cumsales[dup_no!=0 & month(date)==7]
cumsales [dup_no!=0 & month(date)==7] = 1+ disc[dup_no!=0 & month(date)==7]

for(i in 2:length(permno))
{
  if(dup_no[i]!=0 & month(date[i])!=6 & !is.na(lag_sales[i]) & (lag_sales[i])>0)
   {
     cumsales[i] = cumsales[i-1]*(1+disc[i])    
     weight[i] = cumsales[i]*sales_base[i-1]
   } 
if(dup_no[i]!=0 & month(date[i])!=6 & (lag_sales[i])<=0)
   {
     cumsales[i] = cumsales[i-1]*(1+disc[i])
     weight_port[i] = NA
   }
}
```

(The formulae might not make sense as I haven't showed you the entire code.)
The first three lines creates 3 columns of value 0. The next three lines fills in the values of the cells in the columns provided a set of condition is fulfilled. The next for loop tries to fill in the remaining empty values of the columns by calculating new values based on the previous filled in cell values(obtained from lines 5, 6, 7).

The for loop here is taking a lot of time because of the datasize and I need to optimize this code as it will run on a much larger data. Is there any alternative that can be used instead of this for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: R is copy on change (of structure), it sounds like you might be exponentially growing objects. If you have to use for loops make sure the memory size has been pre-allocated whenever you can. Check out the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), the second ring could be relevant to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are generally very time consuming in R. Best avoid them whenever possible. If you search for "vectorization" you will find tons of threads and tutorials discussing the topic.

Just a brief example with your code:

```
index <- dup_no!=0 & month(date)!=6 & !is.na(lag_sales) & (lag_sales)>0
cumsales[index] <- cumsales[which(index)-1]*(1+disc[index])  
weight[index] <- cumsales[index]*sales_base[which(index)-1]
```

This should be able to replace the first part of your for loop.

Comment: Wow! This seems pretty straight forward! Thanks a lot!